# Calling jquery function on document ready and on on.change

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I just updated this function from using `live` to `on` method. Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  function toggle_metaboxes() {

    var format = $('#post-formats-select input[type="radio"]:checked').val();

    $('#orn_metabox_gallery').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#orn_video_link').fadeOut('fast');

    if ('gallery' == format) {
      $('#orn_metabox_gallery').fadeIn('slow');
    } else if ('video' == format) {
      $('#orn_video_link').fadeIn('slow');
    }
  }
  toggle_metaboxes(); // I am calling this function once on document ready
  $(document).on('change', '#post-formats-select input[type="radio"]', toggle_metaboxes)
             .filter(':checked')
             .trigger('change');
});
```

**My Question:** Is there any better way of doing this? I am calling the function on `document ready` and then when radio changes value.

Comment: since you are triggering the change event using `.trigger('change')` there is no need to call ` toggle_metaboxes();`

Comment: @ArunPJohny the problem is I want:
`$('#orn_metabox_gallery').fadeOut('fast');`
`$('#orn_video_link').fadeOut('fast');`
these to be hidden if they are not checked and they dont hide cz there is no change of radio on page load

Answer (score 2):

You can assign multiple events like this:

```
$(document).on('ready change', '#post-formats-select input[type="radio"]', toggle_metaboxes).filter(':checked').trigger('change');
```